# User Input Restrictions in Django generated forms

Tags: python, html, database, django, templates

How can I restrict user input in django generated forms?
Say for example, I have a field(SmallIntegerField) of maxlength=4. How to I restrict the user to only input that? Because without a restriction I get database errors. Am using class-based views.
Thank you

P.S: I want to restrict it in the browser during entry

Comment: You could write a custom validation for the form/formfield. Have a look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Comment: Do you validate your form? How you access to form data?

Comment: do you want to restrict it in the browser during entry or do you just want to validate it on the server, i.e. Django?

Comment: When you say "restrict the user to only input that" are you perhaps referring to input masking? as in, only allowing numeric characters?

Answer (score 1):

Use [MaxValueValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#maxvaluevalidator) validator for that field

```
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

field = models.SmallIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(9999),])
```